# wxMaxima. Definindo uma função de três variáveis

Tags: variáveis, funções, sintaxe, recursão

Estou tentando fazer alguns cálculos simbólicos/algébricos no wxMaxima. Mas estou tendo problemas de sintaxe.

> ***Pergunta.***  *Sejam 'n' e 'm' inteiros previamente estipulados. Qual a sintaxe/'linha de comandos', assim como um procedimento recursivo adequado, para definir uma função 'A(i,j,k)' de três variáveis inteiras 'i','j' e 'k' na linguagem do wxMaxima?*

Gostaria que as variáveis 'i' e 'j' percorressem todos os números inteiros de '1' até 'n'. E que a variável 'k' percorrese todos os inteiros de '0' até 'm'.

O objetivo é usar as saidas 'A(k)(i,j)' como variáveis simbolicas para cálculos agébricos.

**Update 11/08/2016 14h21 (UTC-3)**

A minha area de atuação principal é Matemática teórica. Tenho alguma experiência com algorítimos estruturados em nível teórico e  pouquissima familiaridade com linguagens de programação, compiladores e suas respectivas interfaces. Por isso peço desculpas se esta questão é muito fácil ou não se equadra nas perpectivas do Stackoverflow.

Minhas tentativas podem ser baixadas nos seguintes links: [teste4](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31169801/teste_4.wxm) e [teste3](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/31169801/texte_3.wxm).

**Update 09/08/2016 9h30 (UTC-3)**.  Sendo um pouco mais detalhado com o que quero dizer por cálculo algébrico/simbólico. Tenho um total de simbolos ( ao todo produto n*n*m simbolos ) de variáveis síbolicas 'A(k)(ij)' indexadas por 'i','j' e 'k' com a propriedade que A(k)(i,j)=A(k)(j,i).
De uma forma explícita:

> Se k=1 temos a matriz simétrica A(1) de ordem nxn com entradas siboĺicas A(1)(i,j);
>
> |A(1)(1,1), A(1)(1,2),A(1)(1,3),...,A(1)(1,n) |
>
> |A(1)(2,1), A(1)(2,2),A(1)(2,3),...,A(1)(2,n) |
>
> |A(1)(3,1), A(1)(3,2),A(1)(3,3),...,A(1)(3,n) |
>
> |...................................................................|
>
> |A(1)(1,n), A(1)(2,n),A(1)(3,n),...,A(1)(n,n) |
>
> Se k=2 temos a matriz A(2) de ordem nxn com entradas siboĺicas A(2)(i,j);
>
> |A(2)(1,1), A(2)(1,2),A(2)(1,3),...,A(2)(1,n) |
>
> |A(2)(2,1), A(2)(2,2),A(2)(2,3),...,A(2)(2,n) |
>
> |A(2)(3,1), A(2)(3,2),A(2)(3,3),...,A(2)(3,n) |
>
> |.....................................................................|
>
> |A(2)(n,1), A(2)(n,2),A(2)(n,3)...,A(2)(n,n) |
>
> E assim por diante até chegarmos a matriz  A(m) de ordem nxn com entradas siboĺicas A(m)(i,j);
>
> |A(m)(1,1), A(m)(1,2),A(m)(1,3),...,A(m)(1,n) |
>
> |A(m)(2,1), A(m)(2,2),A(m)(2,3),...,A(m)(2,n) |
>
> |A(m)(3,1), A(m)(3,2),A(m)(3,3),...,A(m)(3,n) |
>
> |....................................................................|
>
> |A(m)(n,1), A(m)(n,2), A(m)(n,3),...,A(m)(n,n) |

Procurei diversos tutoriais na internet sem sucesso.

Espero ter conseguido a clareza necessária para uma resposta objetiva.

Comment: Qual é a relação entre i, j e k? se i e j forem 0 qual é o valor de k? e quando i e j forem 1? e qual é a linguagem que queres usar?

Comment: @Sergio as variáveis 'i', 'j' e 'k' são independentes uma da outra. Ou seja, o valor que 'i' assume não interfere no valor de 'j' ou no valor de 'k', o valor que 'j' assume não interfere no valor de 'i' ou no valor de 'k', o valor que 'k' assume não interfere no valor que 'i' ou 'j'.

Comment: @Sergio quanto a linguagem de programação imaginei que o CAS wxMaxima tenha sua linguarem própria muito parecida com MAPLE ou uma possível variação do C.